# Not able to copy anything from Ubuntu to any Windows drives

Tags: 17.04

I have just installed both Ubuntu Budgie 17.04 and Windows 10 with Creators Update, with disabling Secure Boot, but I cannot copy anything from Ubuntu Budgie to any of the Windows drives from nautilus, paste option is greyed out. I can copy to other USB pen drives, but not to the internal HDD with Primary NTFS Partition Type.

Comment: when you try to copy pest,what message you get??please provide screenshot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Windows partition is read-only as expected in any Windows 8 or newer.

In order to be able to write to the Windows partitions you need to disable Windows' fast startup first. Please be aware that what you intend to do is not advisable.